# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression in json feed content

Tags: javascript, json, blogger, feed

I have the following javascript code

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.x-git.min.js'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[ 

        imgr = new Array();
        imgr[0] = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uitX7ROPtTU/Tyv-G4NA_uI/AAAAAAAAFBY/NcWLPVnYEnU/s1600/no+image.jpg";
        showRandomImg1 = true;
        aBold = true;
        summaryPost = 60;
        summaryPost1 = 180;
        summaryPost2 = 100;
        numposts = 10;
        numposts1 = 6;
          function removeHtmlTag(strx, chop) {
          var s = strx.split("<");
          for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            if (s[i].indexOf(">") != -1) {
              s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">") + 1, s[i].length)
            }
          }
          s = s.join("");
          s = s.substring(0, chop - 1);
          return s;
          }

          function favouritePosts(json) {
          j = (showRandomImg1) ? Math.floor((imgr.length + 1) * Math.random()) : 0;
          img = new Array();
          for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            var pcm;
            var posturl;

             if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
            for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
              if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                break
              }
            }
            for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
              if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                pcm = entry.link[k].title.split(" ")[0];
                break
              }
            }
            if ("content" in entry) {
              var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
              } else if ("summary" in entry) {
                var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
                } else var postcontent = "";
            postdate = entry.published.$t;
            if (j > imgr.length - 1) j = 0;
            img[i] = imgr[j];
            s = postcontent;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) img[i] = d;
            var month = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
            var month2 = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var day = postdate.split("-")[2].substring(0, 2);
            var m = postdate.split("-")[1];
            var y = postdate.split("-")[0];
            var post_id = i;
            var postThumbSize = 600;
            var postThumb = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
            postThumb = postThumb.replace( '/s72-c/', '/s' + postThumbSize + '/' );
            var authorname = entry.author[0].name.$t; 
            var author_img = entry.author[0].gd$image.src;  
            var author_uri = entry.author[0].uri.$t;
            var label_category = entry.category[1].term;
            for (var u2 = 0; u2 < month.length; u2++) {
              if (parseInt(m) == month[u2]) {
                m = month2[u2];
                break
              }
            }

            var address = $(postcontent).find("span.address").html(); 
            var map_point = $(postcontent).find("span.map_point").html(); 



        var item = '<div class="listing-item"><article class="geodir-category-listing fl-wrap"><div class="geodir-category-img"><img src="' + postThumb.replace( '/s72-c/', '/s' + 400 + '/' ) + '" alt=""><div class="overlay"></div></div><div class="geodir-category-content fl-wrap"><a class="listing-geodir-category" href="https://tinosemagazine-new.blogspot.com/search/label/'+label_category+'">'+label_category+'</a><div class="listing-avatar"><a href="'+author_uri+'"><img src="'+author_img+'" alt=""></a><span class="avatar-tooltip">Added By  <strong>'+authorname+'</strong></span></div><h3><a href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></h3><p>'+removeHtmlTag(postcontent,summaryPost1)+'...</p><div class="geodir-category-options fl-wrap"><div class="listing-rating card-popup-rainingvis" data-starrating2="4"><span>(17 reviews)</span></div><div class="geodir-category-location"><a href="#1" class="map-item"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+address+'</a><div id="1"></div></div></div></div></article></div>';
        document.write(item);
        }
}
 //]]>
 </script>
```

The above javascript run with callback, with the following code

```
<script>
                              document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;https:\/\/_______/feeds/posts/summary/-/<data:content/>?max-results=8&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=favouritePosts\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
                            </script>
```

The other elements of feed, like post title, post url, post img are retrieved good but as about post content i have the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Το ξεκίνησε τη λειτουργία του το 2001. Χτίστηκε σε μία έκταση 3 στρεμμάτων στην παραλία της Αγίας Κυριακής, στην περιοχή Άγιος Ιωάννης Πόρτο, σε απόσταση 30 μέτρων από την ακτή. Επιθυμία μας είναι να προσφέρουμε στον επισκέπτη ένα περιβάλλον που συνδυάζει την γαλήνη του Κυκλαδίτικου τοπίου, τα πεντακάθαρα νερά του Αιγαίου και την μοναδικότηττα της Τηνιακής φιλοξενίας.
    at Function.fa.error (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2)
    at favouritePosts ((index):828)
    at Νέα Καταχώρηση?max-results=8&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=favouritePosts:2
fa.error @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
fa.tokenize @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
fa.select @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
fa @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
find @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
n.fn.init @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
n @ jquery-2.x-git.min.js:2
favouritePosts @ (index):828
(anonymous) @ Νέα Καταχώρηση?max-results=8&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=favouritePosts:2
```

Any solution about this?
The same errors is if i have english letters as post content....

Ι dont know if is important this for problem solution but in api callback

```
// API callback
favouritePosts({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$openSearch":"http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$blogger":"http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008","xmlns$georss":"http://www.georss.org/georss","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","xmlns$thr":"http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0","id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-7531200907987340158"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-07-10T08:43:16.528-07:00"},"category":[{"term":"lodging"},{"term":"Νέα Καταχώρηση"},{"term":"Στυλ1"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Tinos on map"},"subtitle":{"type":"html","$t":""},"link":[{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https:\/\/tinosemagazine-new.blogspot.com\/feeds\/posts\/summary"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/7531200907987340158\/posts\/summary\/-\/%CE%9D%CE%AD%CE%B1+%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%87%CF%8E%CF%81%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7?alt=json-in-script\u0026max-results=8\u0026orderby=published"},
```

until this point the above code is in red color, and after that the code became black, that is something generate syntax error in api callback

```
{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https:\/\/_____\/search\/label\/%CE%9D%CE%AD%CE%B1%20%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%87%CF%8E%CF%81%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7"},{"rel":"hub","href":"http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Loukas"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/04860834199108076132"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"16","height":"16","src":"https:\/\/img1.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"}}],"generator":{"version":"7.00","uri":"http://www.blogger.com","$t":"Blogger"},"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"1"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"openSearch$itemsPerPage":{"$t":"8"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-7531200907987340158.post-1538845356800237125"},"published":{"$t":"2019-06-25T04:19:00.000-07:00"},"updated":{"$t":"2019-07-10T07:51:09.432-07:00"},"category":[{"scheme":"http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#","term":"lodging"},{"scheme":"http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#","term":"Νέα Καταχώρηση"},{"scheme":"http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#","term":"Στυλ1"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Nostos Resort"},"summary":{"type":"text","$t":"\u003C\n\nΤο Nostos Resort ξεκίνησε τη λειτουργία του το 2001. Χτίστηκε σε μία έκταση 3 στρεμμάτων στην παραλία της Αγίας Κυριακής, στην περιοχή Άγιος Ιωάννης Πόρτο, σε απόσταση 30 μέτρων από την ακτή. Επιθυμία μας είναι να προσφέρουμε στον επισκέπτη ένα περιβάλλον που συνδυάζει την γαλήνη του Κυκλαδίτικου τοπίου, τα πεντακάθαρα νερά του Αιγαίου και την μοναδικότηττα της Τηνιακής φιλοξενίας.\n\nΑγία "},"link":[{"rel":"replies","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https:\/\/________\/feeds\/1538845356800237125\/comments\/default","title":"Σχόλια ανάρτησης"},{"rel":"replies","type":"text/html","href":"https:\/\/_______\/2019\/06\/nostos-resort.html#comment-form","title":"0 σχόλια"},{"rel":"edit","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/7531200907987340158\/posts\/default\/1538845356800237125"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https:\/\/www.blogger.com\/feeds\/7531200907987340158\/posts\/default\/1538845356800237125"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"https:\/\/________\/2019\/06\/nostos-resort.html","title":"Nostos Resort"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Loukas"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.blogger.com\/profile\/04860834199108076132"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"16","height":"16","src":"https:\/\/img1.blogblog.com\/img\/b16-rounded.gif"}}],"media$thumbnail":{"xmlns$media":"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/","url":"https:\/\/1.bp.blogspot.com\/-EpGgot5jz9A\/XRvJibRcz1I\/AAAAAAAAl1s\/5KupjmPmAKEovM0lozwYs637uk-CDp-eACLcBGAs\/s72-c\/02.jpg","height":"72","width":"72"},"thr$total":{"$t":"0"}}]}});
```

Ok, the problem are dots inside text...For some reason , a dot inside post content generates error in json feed....How to solve it?

Comment: Seems the endpoint is not sending JSONP as you are expecting it to

Comment: What is the wrong? The type of letters? Any special character in post content?

Comment: No... the structure of the whole response is wrong

Comment: The line `b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);` and `c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);` have incorrect quotes.

Comment: I've changed the quotes....nothing....This part of code is in order to retrieve the main image from post content, and this element is retrieved normally....

Comment: Very simple problem - UR looking for something missing by var address = $(postcontent).find("span.address").html();  in a strange plain text looking string: <\n\nΤο Nostos Resort ξεκίνησε τη λειτουργία του το 2001. Χτίστηκε σε μία έκταση 3 στρεμμάτων στην παραλία της Αγίας Κυριακής, στην περιοχή Άγιος Ιωάννης Πόρτο, σε απόσταση 30 μέτρων από την ακτή. Επιθυμία μας είναι να προσφέρουμε στον επισκέπτη ένα περιβάλλον που συνδυάζει την γαλήνη του Κυκλαδίτικου τοπίου, τα πεντακάθαρα νερά του Αιγαίου και την μοναδικότηττα της Τηνιακής φιλοξενίας.\n\nΑγία